# UITextView textContainer.exclusionPaths not working well

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableViewCell with a UITextView and a button that appears when the tableview and cell are in edit mode (isEditing = true). I set the editing mode with `setEditing(, animated: )` in my view controller. In the cell, I need that no text appears behind the button when it is visible. This is controlled within `layoutSubviews()` in my cell class:

```
import UIKit

class NoteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak private var noteTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var editNoteButton: UIButton!
    
    var note: String? {
        didSet {
            noteTextView.text = note
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if isEditing {
            guard let exlusionFrame = editNoteButton.frame(in: noteTextView) else {return}
            noteTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: exlusionFrame)]
            editNoteButton.isHidden = false
        }
        else {
            noteTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = []
            editNoteButton.isHidden = true
        }
        // super.layoutSubviews() Putting this here does not change anything
    }
}
```

Even though the code is executed as expected when the view controller is set to edit mode, there is text behind the button. See next picture.

[The result is not as desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRRKp.png)

I found out that if I put the iPhone in landscape mode while in edit mode, the text is then drawn as expected and the behaviour is also as expected after Save/Edit, even when back to portrait mode.

[Expected result in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08bPY.png)

[Expected result in non edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSQG7.png)

Does someone has an idea about what is wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you.